# Using Local Storage on For-Loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, save, local-storage

I'm new to JavaScript and i'm trying to create a code where for each checkbox item checked, a point is added to the id=result THEN the result is saved in local storage. Problem is, it won't save the generated result.

```
<script>
 function score() {
 var score = document.forms[0];
 var i;
 var points=0;
 if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  for (i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
    if (score[i].checked) {
        points++;
    }
 }
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Current Score: " + points;
 localStorage.setItem= ("points", JSON.stringify(points));
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('points');

}
else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does 
not support web storage...";
     }
}
</script>
```

It shows the result but it does not save it. Any help would be appreciated :)

**Edit**
Changed 
    localStorage.setItem= ("points", JSON.stringify(points)); 
to
    localStorage.setItem("points", JSON.stringify(points));
As suggested by [Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7216648/moon)
But now it won't show the results.

Answer (score 3):

Fix

```
localStorage.setItem= ("points", JSON.stringify(points));
```

to

```
localStorage.setItem("points", JSON.stringify(points));
```

And, as a different way, you can also just check like this to know if `localStorage` exsits. 
Just to let you know :)

```
if(!window.localStorage){
    ... do something ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks man didn't see that error. But now the results won't appear. I think the placement of the localStorage.setItem("points", JSON.stringify(points)); overwrites the result though. Will update as soon as possible

Comment: Still doesn't work? Please update your question and tag me so I can help you out, man :)